# Magento show products with multiple categories on CMS page

Tags: php, magento

I added a new CMS page in my magento site. The name of the page is "1+1 offer". I am trying to display products of that a category "1+1 offer".

I am using this code to display the category products.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="365" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

While category id of "1+1 offer" category is 365.

Now my problem is, If I add new products to that category, they are showing up in CMS page. But if I add already existing products from other categories, they are not showing up.

For example : "Axe deodorant" product already belongs to "body sprays" category. If I open up that product and add "1+1 offer" category to it, it is not showing up in the CMS page. If I remove the old category "body sprays", and keep only new category "1+1 offer", then it is showing up in that page.

But I want to display the products though both the categories are checked for the products. Can anyone help me?

---

**Edit :**

The mistake I did was adding the new category to second root category instead of adding it to Default Category. See the picture "1+1 offer zone". When I added it to Default Category, It worked.

I don't know the reason though. :) Tell me if anyone knows.

[image]

Comment: Tried it on a fresh clean Magento and wasn't able to reproduce. All products appear even if products are attached to 1 or more other categories. Are you sure you don't have some module overriding catalog list and / or something in list.phtml that changes normal behavior?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Please check.